# How to pass error message from Controller Action to Form on form submit.

Tags: zend-framework2

while creating form, form validation is easy. But how can one validate submitted data and pass error message back to form.

For example I have a form for password change, SO I need to verify old password and check if new password and confirm password are same, and in failure stage, Show message on password edit form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean that in your view script ?

```
<?php if ($form->getMessages()){
    // alert
    ?>
    <div class="alert alert-error">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert" type="button">×</button>
        <strong><?php echo $this->translate("Are you awake ?"); ?></strong>
        <?php echo $this->translate("Some data are not filled out correctly."); ?>
    </div>       
    <?php
}?>
```

After just print the errors from **$form->getMessages()**

Answer (score 1):

If setup correctly the form will do this for you. The form will run the validation checks and then you can use the formElementErrors view helper to disalay the errors.
Can you paste some code of how your form is setup?

An example of display validation errors in the form view:

```
<?php $form->prepare() ?>
<?php echo $this->form()->openTag($form); ?>
    <?php foreach($form->getElements() as $element): ?>
        <div class="control-group">
        <?php /* @var $element \Zend\From\Element */ ?>
        <?php if($element->getLabel()): ?>
             <?php echo $this->formLabel($element) ?>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php // Show any validation errors for this element ?>
        <?php echo $this->formElementErrors($element); ?>
        <?php echo $this->formElement($element) ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach ?>
<?php echo $this->form()->closeTag() ?>
```